# The meaning of "parallel xxx products"?

Tags: meaning

In the following sentence,

> **Parallel xxx products** in the market will impact our sales.

What is the definition or meaning of "parallel xxx products"?

Comment: Please quote more from that text

Comment: There is no context for this sentence, I read poeple were discussing the translation of it in Sina Weibo (Chinese Twitter).

Comment: If you can't tell us what was in the place of XXX then can you tell us what sort of word was there? (Unless it actually was XXX in the original, in which case it would mean "competing pornographic products that fill the same niche as our pornographic products").

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided text, I expect that it simply means *competing products*. These could be products from competitors or from the same manufacturer. Products can also be *introduced in parallel* (at the same time).

Comment: I think you are right on with *competing*. I think *parallel* probably refers to a nearly identical feature set rather than to time of introduction.

Comment: Thank you. Could there be any other explanation, like counterfeit, or grey products?

Comment: @user36806 That cannot be inferred from the limited context that you've provided.

Comment: While the blocking of a word doesn't help us, this is what I'd say too. I'd also understand it as *not* counterfeit or grey products, as their unfair path to the market would not parallel that of a legitimate product.